# Как выбрать строки, содержащие в столбце данные, которые есть в столбце другого фрейма данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм `df1`:

```
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
1  24  25  34   2
2  43  11  77  87
3  34   2   2  34
4   3  55  19  11
5  42  74  29  44
6  54   9  11  12
```

и `df2`:

```
    b
0   4
1  11
2   2
3   9
```

Нужно выбрать из `df1` строки, содержащие в столбце `b` значения, которые также содержит в своем столбце `b` фрейм данных `df2`.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
2  43  11  77  87
3  34   2   2  34
6  54   9  11  12
```

Мой код возвращает вообще булевы значения:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[23, 4, 34, 12], [24, 25, 34, 2], [43, 11, 77, 87],
                   [34, 2, 2, 34], [3, 55, 19, 11], [42, 74, 29, 44], [54, 9, 11, 12]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4], [11], [2], [9]])
df1.rename({0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.rename({0: 'b'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df3 = df2['b'].isin(df1['b'])

print(df3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вариант 1:

```
In [229]: res = df1.merge(df2)

In [230]: res
Out[230]:
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
1  43  11  77  87
2  34   2   2  34
3  54   9  11  12
```

если нужно сохранить исходные индексы:

```
In [231]: res = df1.reset_index().merge(df2).set_index("index").rename_axis(None)

In [232]: res
Out[232]:
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
2  43  11  77  87
3  34   2   2  34
6  54   9  11  12
```

---

#### Вариант 2:

```
In [234]: res = df1.query("b in @df2.b")

In [235]: res
Out[235]:
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
2  43  11  77  87
3  34   2   2  34
6  54   9  11  12
```

Answer (score 4):

```
res = df1[df1["b"].isin(df2["b"])]
```

res:

```
    a   b   c   d
0  23   4  34  12
2  43  11  77  87
3  34   2   2  34
6  54   9  11  12
```